# Accumulate messages before call Actor on Akka

Tags: akka, akka-stream

I'm implementing a throttle using Akka Stream and it's almost working. It's almost working because I would like to send a list of messages instead a single one each time. I'm not sure if Akka's Actors allow to accumulate mesages before call actor.

I know that the following example is simple but in real scenario, I'll be receiving tons of messages from RabbitMQ and I want to call actor after some seconds to avoid a too high rate - after receive the message, I'll call a webservice.

Here is what I did:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, OverflowStrategy, ThrottleMode}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object AkkaStream {
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("HelloSystem")
    val actor = system.actorOf(Props[ToughActor])
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system)
    val throttler: ActorRef =
      Source.actorRef(bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
        .throttle(2, 5.second, 2, ThrottleMode.Shaping)
        .to(Sink.actorRef(actor, NotUsed))
        .run()

    throttler ! CoolThing("message 1")
    throttler ! CoolThing("message 2")
    throttler ! CoolThing("message 3")
    throttler ! CoolThing("message 4")
    throttler ! CoolThing("message 5")
  }
}

class ToughActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case x => println(x.getClass)
  }
}

case class CoolThing(name: String)
```

On my example, I would like to receive a collection of maximum 2 objects on `receive` function instead `receive` be called twice.

If I sent 2 messages (eg.: `CoolThing("message 1")` and `CoolThing("message 2")`), Is possible to receive on Actor a `List(CoolThing("message 1"), CoolThing("message 2")`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a grouping function not a throttle. Or maybe one after the other.

Eg,

```
 Source.actorRef(bufferSize = 1000, OverflowStrategy.dropNew)
    .groupedWithin(2, 2.seconds)
    .to(Sink.actorRef(actor, NotUsed))
    .run()
```

For more http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.4.2/akka/stream/scaladsl/FlowOps.html#groupedWithin-int-scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration-